# User Input as regex not working in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

When I use the following code, it works:

```
String input = "8:32:03";
String filter = "(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2})";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(filter);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.find()) {  //Enters the condition.
    System.out.println("Found => " + m.group() );
}
```

However, when I try to take user input as regex it does not work?

```
String input = "8:32:03";
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String filter = reader.nextLine();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(filter);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.find()) {  //Does not enter the condition.
    System.out.println("Found => " + m.group() );
}
```

I tried using `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(filter));`
But that does not work either.
How can I take user input as a valid regex?

Comment: What is your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am making an assumption here.. Are you inputting `(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2})` ?

If so, the `\\` in your example act as escape for the `\`.. so for your input to be the same, you would need: `(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})`